# How to Connect Pt 1000

Tags: arduino, sensors, temperature

I am trying to connect a 2-wired PT 1000 to a micro-controller board .... Does anyone has any idea how this should be done? I did not try anything since I am afraid to blow the ADC of the board

Comment: Better asked on the http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PT1000 is a RTD (Resistive Tempurature Device) max resistance of 1000 ohms. You can simply use a voltage divider, as shown in the picture. Since it is a passive circuit, now way to exceed 5V, it is safe.

[image]

Ideally you will want to bias the divider to mid range (or 2.5v). So you will want to replace the 3.9K with something better. But the below will get you initially going.

Comment: by any chance do you have a guide software for the PT1000 or PT100 because I did not find any